# JQuery Waypoints - multiple triggers for divs with same ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm using http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints .

I want it to fire every time a div with id="project" hits the top of the viewport. There is more than one div with this ID however it only works for the first div and none afterwards.

I'd really rather not use classes as it would confuse other areas of my code.

```
$('#project').waypoint(function() {
alert('Hello world');
});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `id` should always be unique.

Comment: If your other code is depending on multiple elements to have the same id, then it is already confused.  `document.getElementById` will only ever return at most 1 element.

Comment: The reason I'm reluctant to use classes is because the behavior on waypoint is to add and remove class and I'm getting really confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery assumes that an id selector is unique and therefore only returns the first item it finds that matches.

So two possible solutions could be:

- to use classes
- or to use different ID's, like `uniqueid-1`, `uniqueid-2`, `uniqueid-3`, etc... Then use the attribute selector to match the substring in the id, `$('[id^=uniqueid]')`